# A way to control Google Earth from Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, google-earth

I have dowloaded a python script that uses `win32com` module ([project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)) to start and control Google Earth aplication on Windows. The commands in the script can also be used to interactively control Google Earth from command line.

The code is [here](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dgqhgsgm_933rjw93). It works, it is exciting, BUT...

I'd like to do the same ON LINUX (Ubuntu derivatives).

The problem is: this script uses the COM interface to pass commands to GoogleEarth via interprocess communication. On linux, instead of an .exe, there is `googleearth-bin` executable, and I don't know how it would or shoud be to use the same interprocess communication idea on Linux.

Since the program is most probably compiled to the different OSes from (mostly) the same source code, it "seems" to me that the functionality could be in there. Now about HOW to access it from a Python script, this goes way beyond my current knowledge.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Earth COM Api has been depreciated (see http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/sunset-for-google-earth-com-api.html) so writing code against it is going to be hard-work and there are no guarantees that your code will work in the future.

Google are suggesting that people use the Plugin version of Google Earth but unfortunately, to date, this isn't supported on Linux OSs so that is not an option for you in this case.

Anyhow, caveates aside, you could look at something like pygoogleearth

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygoogleearth/

This is a pythonic wrapper around the Google Earth COM Interface, it should allow you to work with the COM api in python or at the least give you some pointers on the set-up.

Comment: Yes I know - hence "at the least give you some pointers on the set-up" - in any case both the COM api and plugin are now depreciated so nothing is going to work for very much longer...